# What is the significance of class body being executable?

Tags: ruby

Class body is executable like in this code:

```
3.times do
  class C
    puts "hello"
  end
end
```

What is the significance of that? I don't see the significance of class
body being executable. Is it because we need the code at the top
level to execute, or is it to be able to return a value? If that is not the only reason, is there a good example to show that it is a brilliant idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a couple of easy examples:

It allows things like attribute accessors to work:

```
class Dog
  attr_reader :name
end
```

`attr_reader` and others from that family are just methods that are executed in context where `self` is a class object. They are not declaractions; they actually execute as the class is being executed. It thus hinges on the ability of Ruby to call methods while defining a class.

It allows conditional definition:

```
class OptimisedClass
  if defined? JRUBY_VERSION
    def do_stuff
      jruby_optimised_stuff
    end
  else
    def stuff
      c_optimised_stuff
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes Ruby more consistent as a language to have class, module, and function definitions be executable.  For example, you can use an `if` statement to decide whether or not to define the class.  Here is an example where we only define a class if we are running under JRuby:

```
if RUBY_ENGINE == 'jruby'
  class SomeClass
  end
end
```

If you come from a C++ or Java background, you think of the class structure as this unchanging thing defined at compile time, and you can only control it with #ifdefs.  But in Ruby, it can be changed on the fly, using actual Ruby code instead of some preprocessor.

ActiveRecord is a popular Ruby ORM gem that reads your database structure at runtime and uses its column information to help set up the classes that represent each table.